# Smallest positive integer $x$,whose last digit is 6 and if we erase this 6 and put it in left most of the number so obtained,the number becomes $4x$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Determine the smallest positive integer $x$, whose last digit is $6$ and if we erase this $6$ and put it in left most of the number so obtained, the number becomes $4x$.

**My work**.
$x = 10a + 6$ and $4x = 20a + 24$
Last 2 digits are 46.
Form = $100b + 46$.
$$4x = 400b + 100 + 84$$
Last digits $= 846$.
Similarly I continued these steps and this way the question seems to be never ending.

Comment: I am in class XI.

Comment: just change everything into algebraic equations. this doesn't even need modular arithmetic ...

Comment: Don't give up so easily! You must have tried something...

Comment: Tell us about your ideas in words if you don't know how to write it mathematically.

Comment: I want to write mathematically. Can I do it from Android?

Answer (score 3):

Hint. If $x$ has $n$ digits then $x=10y+6$ for some positive integer $y$ and 
$$6\cdot 10^{n-1}+y=4x=40y+24.$$
Now find $y$ (which depends on $n$). What is the smallest value for $n$ such that $y$ is a positive integer?

Comment: How to write Mathematics? I am using Android and I want to show my work on this question.

Comment: @user468650 Just write your mathematics as text. I will help you to convert it into LaTex.

Comment: But where I should write again?

Comment: I want to write my procedure. Where to write it?

Comment: @user468650 Just edit your question and write after "my work".

Comment: Sir can you solve further?

Comment: @user468650 in the second equation, $4x=20a+24$ you forgot to use the infomation that a digit $6$ is in the front. Try to follow my hint and find $y$,

Comment: @Robert Can I ask a question pertaining to this problem?

Comment: @Robert Thank you very much.

Comment: @Viraam Please, ask your question!

Comment: @Robert I tried solving it and arrived at something that looks like this: $ \frac{6 \times 10^{n-1} -24}{39} = y$. I'm not pretty sure how to find smallest possible $n$ using modular arithmetic. However I did find out by brute force that $n=6$ satisfies.

Comment: @Viraam same thing I did. You have $$6\cdot 10^{n-1}\equiv 24\pmod{39} \iff 2\cdot 10^{n-1}\equiv 8\pmod{13}$$. Don't see a way to get $n=6$ as the least other than trial and error.

Comment: @Viraam Yes, we obtain $y=\frac{2 \times 10^{n-1} -8}{13}$ then we find $n$ such that $2 \times 10^{n-1} -8$ is divisible by $13$, Brute force is fine here. Note that by Fermat's theorem we have to check for $1\leq n\leq 12$.

Comment: @Alvin I'll stick on to trial and error then. Thanks

Comment: $615384=4\times 153846$

Comment: @Raffaele Yes, that is the number!